# shell script removes ' when used in echo

Tags: shell, unix

I am preparing dynamic control file from shell script. While doing so i am printing a line as

```
echo 'TEST               "lpad(trim(replace(:TEST1,'-','')),9,'0')",'` to a file `test.txt
```

But when i use above statement my shell is removing `'` from the line i.e.

```
TEST NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER SQL
string for column : "lpad(trim(replace(:TEST1,-,)),9,0)"
```

here we can that the single quotes are removed.

Any one please help me why is it happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why is it happening?

Single quotes don't nest. So one single quote ends the quoting and another one re-starts another quoting.

```
echo 'inside single quotes'outside single quotes'inside single quotes'
```

If you want to have the literal single quotes in your output, stop single quoting, escape the quoting character and restart single quoting with `'\''`:

```
 echo 'TEST               "lpad(trim(replace(:TEST1,'\''-'\'','\'\'')),9,'\''0'\'')",'
```

or use double quotes:

```
 echo "TEST               \"lpad(trim(replace(:TEST1,'-','')),9,'0')\","
```